# Static code analyzer as pre-commit hook for Emacs-LISP

Tags: git, lisp, elisp, static-analysis

I want to add a static code checker as a pre-commit hook on my Emacs-Lisp code, mainly for catching errors such as `Symbol’s function definition is void`.

[Static code analysis tool for Common Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987556/static-code-analysis-tool-for-common-lisp) suggests `lisp-critic` ([original](http://quickdocs.org/lisp-critic/) and [remake](https://www.xach.com/lisp/)). It uses [ASDF (Another System Definition Facility)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_System_Definition_Facility), which I'd need to install on my machine, and wrap the call to `lisp-critic` in a bash script in `.git/hooks/pre-commit` as in [Git: Prevent commits in master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462111/git-prevent-commits-in-master-branch).

[The documentation for `lisp-critic`](http://quickdocs.org/lisp-critic/) uses inline code:

```lisp
 (critique
    (defun count-a (lst)
      (setq n 0)
      (dolist (x lst)
        (if (equal x 'a)
          (setq n (+ n 1))))
      n))
```

and I'm not sure if the package analyzes code defined in a separate file. And I also don't know if `lisp-critic` is compatible with Emacs-LISP.

Has anyone set up a similar system who can give me some pointers?

Comment: There's pretty much zero chance lisp-critic will work for elisp: elisp's last common ancestor with CL was in the late 1970s.  Wouldn't using some kind of test framework be better?

Comment: Yes, probably. I found the Emacs function `elint-file` and attempted to include it in a pre-commit hook, but `emacs --batch -f package-initialize --eval "(elint-file 'functions.el')"` throws `Invalid read syntax: ")"` when running it from Emacs does not; and also to include it in an ERT test with `(ert-deftest lint-free () (should (equal (elint-file ...))` in the file but couldn't find how to refer to the file from the file itself.